# Expectation of the ratio between Beta-Prime and Gamma random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, ratio, gamma-distribution

Given two random variables, $V \sim \beta^{'}(P,PM)$ and $U \sim \Gamma(PM,\zeta)$, where $\beta^{'}$ is the Beta-Prime distribution, $\Gamma$ is the Gamma distribution and $\zeta$ is a real constant value.

What would be the result of the following expectation?

$$E \left[ \frac{V}{U}  \right] = ?$$

Comment: You need the joint distribution for that. If $U$ and $V$ are independent, the result is $EV\cdot E(U^{-1})$, naturally.

Comment: In what cases could we consider $V$ and $U$ as independent r.v.s?